# How can I validate the first part of a form with jQuery Validator without submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have two form parts and I need them to be valid before each part's button will work. I have tried several methods but I am still doing something wrong. Normally on submit I have no problem. In this example I have a next button and on form part two I have a submit button. I need to validate each form on button press.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#part-one").validate({
          rules: {
              fname: { required: true },
              age: { required: true }
          },
          messages: {
              fname: { required: "* required" },
              age: { required: "* required" }
          },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
          $("#part-one").fadeOut();
          $("#part-two").fadeIn();

          return false;  // block the default submit action
      }
  });
})
```

I have a fiddle that better illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/simplymarkb/asw5rdph/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the form validation a function, and execute this function when the `next button` is clicked. If the form is valid, show the next part.

Here is an updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2h6x0j31/1/

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did there. Good idea. Thanks!